# How to mock SharedPreferences.getInstance()?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to mock SharedPreferences.getInstance() in Flutter Test?
I have searched on Google and found no answers.
I also tried ChatGPT and came up with this:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class MockSharedPreferences extends Mock implements SharedPreferences {}

void main() {
  group(
    'Login Tests', 
    () {
      testWidgets('Login', (WidgetTester tester) async {
        final mockSharedPreferences = MockSharedPreferences();
        // Not working.
        when(() => MockSharedPreferences.getInstance()).thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(mockSharedPreferences));
      });    
    }
  );
}
```

The login function in the lib that has to be executed fully: (It gets stuck at the SharedPreferences.getInstance() line, that's why I want to mock it)

```
  void login() {
    if (
      username.isNotEmpty
      && password.isNotEmpty
    ) {
      dio.post(
        '${Config.url}/api/users/login/',
        data: {
          'username': username,
          'password': password
        }
      ).then(
        (Response<dynamic> response) async {
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            String token = response.data['key'];
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            sharedPreferences.setString('token', token);
            BlocProvider.of<AccountBloc>(context).add(LoginEvent(token));
            Future.delayed(
              Duration.zero, 
              () async {
                Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('/');
              }
            );                  
          } else {
            throw 'Data: ${response.data}. Code: ${response.statusCode}. Message: ${response.statusMessage}';
          }
        }
      ).catchError(
        (dynamic error) {
          print('Login error: ${error}');
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to use SharedPreferences in tests is to use the `setMockInitialValues()` method, as reported on the official package: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences.

Also, look at this for a complete example: https://blog.victoreronmosele.com/mocking-shared-preferences-flutter

An example:

```dart
test('Mock data in SharedPreferences', () async {

  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({'test': 1});
  SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  expect(sp.getInt('test'), 1);

});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to use SharedPreferences in the test code, instead I want the code in the login function to be executed (I added new code to my question).

Comment: Not sure why the answer isn't the answer.  But if you want a full mock, put your SharedPreferences singleton inside a locator, like get_it, or Riverpod, and then substitute that during your tests.

Comment: If i understand well, you're invoking the `login()` function directly in your test, right? Try to add `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});` before invoking `login()`.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz It's answering a different thing.